# How to solve response code 403 from AWS in an Android project?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, retrofit

I am using retrofit to make a POST call to AWS server. It gives me the following error
`Response{protocol=h2, code=403, message=, url=https://9oe8xt95sj.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/voip-dev-wa/staging/Device/registerCustomer}`

My Retrofit method is as below

```
Retrofit retrofit;
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiService.API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
```

ApiService.java

```
String API_BASE_URL = "SOME String";

    @POST("registerCustomer")
    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "accept: application/json"})
    Call<RegisterResponse> register(@Body Register register);
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I did not pass the access token as the header. So it is responding forbidden error.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request.Builder ongoing = chain.request().newBuilder();
                ongoing.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                ongoing.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
                ongoing.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AppSetting.getInstance().getSDKDataManager().getAccessToken());
                return chain.proceed(ongoing.build());
            }
        });
```